# Android SQlite exceptions which cause the app to crash

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite

I've been scratching my head for hours now trying to figure out why my android program crashes.

I've been getting two different errors:

- **java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo**
- **android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FROM": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  id, forename, surname, housenumber, street, town, county, postcode, phone,  FROM contacts WHERE id=?**

this happens when i press my buttons after the program starts.

I have 5 different Classes, two handle the database, the other 3 handle the information and functionality of the program.

LOGCAT

```
Process: com.example.rockodile.contactsappliaction, PID: 11603
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rockodile.contactsappliaction/com.example.rockodile.contactsappliaction.ContactDetails}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FROM": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  id, forename, surname, housenumber, street, town, county, postcode, phone,  FROM contacts WHERE id=?
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FROM": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  id, forename, surname, housenumber, street, town, county, postcode, phone,  FROM contacts WHERE id=?
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1318)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1257)
at com.example.rockodile.contactsappliaction.UserSQL.getContactById(UserSQL.java:136)
at com.example.rockodile.contactsappliaction.ContactDetails.onCreate(ContactDetails.java:58)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

The Logcat shows that the are two problems, one is on my UserSQL class on line 136

the other is on my ContactDetails class on line 58

#### UserSQL.java

```
public class UserSQL  {
    private DBHelper dbHelper;

    public UserSQL(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    }

    public int insert(Contact contact) {

        //Open connection to write data
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Contact.KEY_FORENAME, contact.forename);
        values.put(Contact.KEY_SURNAME, contact.surname);
        values.put(Contact.KEY_HOUSENUMEBR, contact.housenumber);
        values.put(Contact.KEY_STREET, contact.street);
        values.put(Contact.KEY_TOWN, contact.town);
        values.put(Contact.KEY_COUNTY, contact.county);
        values.put(Contact.KEY_POSTCODE, contact.postcode);
        values.put(Contact.KEY_PHONE, contact.phone);
        values.put(Contact.KEY_EMAIL, contact.email);

        // Inserting Row
        long contact_Id = db.insert(Contact.TABLE, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
        return (int) contact_Id;
    }

    public void delete(int contact_Id) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        // It's a good practice to use parameter ?, instead of concatenate string
        db.delete(Contact.TABLE, Contact.KEY_ID + "= ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(contact_Id) });
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    public void update(Contact contact) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(Contact.KEY_FORENAME, contact.forename);
        values.put(Contact.KEY_SURNAME, contact.surname);
        values.put(Contact.KEY_HOUSENUMEBR, contact.housenumber);
        values.put(Contact.KEY_STREET, contact.street);
        values.put(Contact.KEY_TOWN, contact.town);
        values.put(Contact.KEY_COUNTY, contact.county);
        values.put(Contact.KEY_POSTCODE, contact.postcode);
        values.put(Contact.KEY_PHONE, contact.phone);
        values.put(Contact.KEY_EMAIL, contact.email);

        // It's a good practice to use parameter ?, instead of concatenate string
        db.update(Contact.TABLE, values, Contact.KEY_ID + "= ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(contact.contact_ID) });
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getContactList() {
        //Open connection to read only
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String selectQuery =  "SELECT  " +
                Contact.KEY_ID + "," +
                Contact.KEY_FORENAME + ", " +
                Contact.KEY_SURNAME + ", " +
                Contact.KEY_HOUSENUMEBR  + ", " +
                Contact.KEY_STREET + ", " +
                Contact.KEY_TOWN + ", " +
                Contact.KEY_COUNTY  + ", " +
                Contact.KEY_POSTCODE + ", " +
                Contact.KEY_PHONE + ", " +
                " FROM " + Contact.TABLE;


        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                HashMap<String, String> record = new HashMap<String, String>();
                record.put("id", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contact.KEY_ID)));
                record.put("forename", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contact.KEY_FORENAME)));
                record.put("surname", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contact.KEY_SURNAME)));
                record.put("housenumber", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contact.KEY_HOUSENUMEBR)));
                record.put("street", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contact.KEY_STREET)));
                record.put("town", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contact.KEY_TOWN)));
                record.put("county", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contact.KEY_COUNTY)));
                record.put("postcode", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contact.KEY_POSTCODE)));
                record.put("phone", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contact.KEY_PHONE)));
                record.put("email", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contact.KEY_EMAIL)));
                contactList.add(record);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return contactList;

    }

    public Contact getContactById(int Id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String selectQuery =  "SELECT  " +
                Contact.KEY_ID + ", " +
                Contact.KEY_FORENAME + ", " +
                Contact.KEY_SURNAME + ", " +
                Contact.KEY_HOUSENUMEBR  + ", " +
                Contact.KEY_STREET + ", " +
                Contact.KEY_TOWN + ", " +
                Contact.KEY_COUNTY  + ", " +
                Contact.KEY_POSTCODE + ", " +
                Contact.KEY_PHONE + ", " +
                " FROM " + Contact.TABLE
                + " WHERE " +
                Contact.KEY_ID + "=?";// It's a good practice to use parameter ?, instead of concatenate string

        int iCount =0;
        Contact contact = new Contact();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] { String.valueOf(Id) } );

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                contact.contact_ID =cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contact.KEY_ID));
                contact.forename =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contact.KEY_FORENAME));
                contact.surname  =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contact.KEY_SURNAME));
                contact.housenumber =cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contact.KEY_HOUSENUMEBR));
                contact.street =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contact.KEY_STREET));
                contact.town =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contact.KEY_TOWN));
                contact.county =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contact.KEY_COUNTY));
                contact.postcode =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contact.KEY_POSTCODE));
                contact.phone =cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contact.KEY_PHONE));
                contact.email =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contact.KEY_EMAIL));

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return contact;
    }

}
```

#### ContactDetails.java

```
public class ContactDetails extends ActionBarActivity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    Button btnSave ,  btnDelete;
    Button btnClose;
    EditText forename;
    EditText surname;
    EditText housenumber;
    EditText street;
    EditText town;
    EditText county;
    EditText postcode;
    EditText phone;
    EditText email;

    private int _contact_Id = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_detail);

        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);
        btnClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.close);

        forename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.forename);
        surname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.surname);
        housenumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.housenumber);
        street = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.street);
        town = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.town);
        county = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.county);
        postcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.postcode);
        phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnClose.setOnClickListener(this);


        _contact_Id =0;
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        _contact_Id  =intent.getIntExtra("contact_Id", 0);
        UserSQL repo = new UserSQL(this);
        Contact contact_information;
        contact_information = repo.getContactById(_contact_Id);

        housenumber.setText(String.valueOf(contact_information.housenumber));
        surname.setText(contact_information.surname);
        forename.setText(contact_information.forename);
        street.setText(contact_information.street);
        town.setText(contact_information.town);
        county.setText(contact_information.county);
        postcode.setText(contact_information.postcode);
        phone.setText(String.valueOf(contact_information.phone));
        email.setText(contact_information.email);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (view == findViewById(R.id.save)) {
            UserSQL repo = new UserSQL(this);
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.housenumber = Integer.parseInt(housenumber.getText().toString());
            contact.phone = Integer.parseInt(phone.getText().toString());
            contact.forename = forename.getText().toString();
            contact.surname = surname.getText().toString();
            contact.street = street.getText().toString();
            contact.town = town.getText().toString();
            contact.county = county.getText().toString();
            contact.postcode = postcode.getText().toString();

            contact.contact_ID = _contact_Id;

            if (_contact_Id == 0) {
                _contact_Id = repo.insert(contact);

                Toast.makeText(this, "New contact created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                repo.update(contact);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Contact updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.delete)) {
            UserSQL repo = new UserSQL(this);
            repo.delete(_contact_Id);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Contact Record Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            finish();
        } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.close)) {
            finish();


        }

    }
}
```

Once the program runs, i have two buttons, one to view the contacts, and one to add a new contact. pressing any of those buttons causes the program to shutdown and crash.

however i get different errors when i press each.
The error you can see above you is when i press the ADD button.
The error i get when i press the VIEW button is the following

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FROM": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  id,forename, surname, housenumber, street, town, county, postcode, phone,  FROM contacts


at com.example.rockodile.contactsappliaction.UserSQL.getContactList(UserSQL.java:90)
                                                                                               at com.example.rockodile.contactsappliaction.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:52)
```

The full logcat for the second arrow is below.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.rockodile.contactsappliaction, PID: 13715
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FROM": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  id,forename, surname, housenumber, street, town, county, postcode, phone,  FROM contacts
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1318)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1257)
   at com.example.rockodile.contactsappliaction.UserSQL.getContactList(UserSQL.java:90)
   at com.example.rockodile.contactsappliaction.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:52)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I just want to know what the problem is, i have tried everything that has been suggested. Am i missing something obvious? i have used this approach before and checked against the previous version which works just fine and its identical however this one does not work.

I highly appreciate any suggestions

Comment: You have an extra comma after the last column name before `FROM`.

Comment: Maybe this question have become too complicated as i've made so many different changes to the question. my first problem was solved so i thank you guys for helping and have marked the question as Solved.

Comment: Yeah, don't change your question like that after it's been answered. That's probably why you got downvoted. Anyway, just so you don't have to post all this again, look at line 105 of your `getContactList()` method. Looks like whichever column you're trying to get there doesn't exist in the `Cursor`. Looks like email, since that's not in your query, which might also explain why you had that dangling comma.

Comment: Wow. that is the the error. IT FULLY WORKS NOW!

Comment: Pro tips for posting: once something is solved by virtue of an answer being received, please do not invalidate that work by changing the whole question. Do not add answers to your questions, if you want to add a solution that is not mentioned below, you can add a self-answer. I have rolled back to the last good question. If you have further queries please ask a new question.

Comment: @halfer Thank you for the tip. sorry i'm new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this error here.

```
Process: com.example.rockodile.contactsappliaction, PID: 5549
                                                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                                                                                             at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
                                                                                             at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
                                                                                             at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
                                                                                             at com.example.rockodile.contactsappliaction.UserSQL.getContactList(UserSQL.java:105)
                                                                                             at com.example.rockodile.contactsappliaction.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:52)
```

Update.

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getContactList() {
        //Open connection to read only
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String selectQuery =  "SELECT  " +
                Contact.KEY_ID + "," +
                Contact.KEY_FORENAME + ", " +
                Contact.KEY_SURNAME + ", " +
                Contact.KEY_HOUSENUMEBR  + ", " +
                Contact.KEY_STREET + ", " +
                Contact.KEY_TOWN + ", " +
                Contact.KEY_COUNTY  + ", " +
                Contact.KEY_POSTCODE + ", " +
                Contact.KEY_PHONE + ", " +
                " FROM " + Contact.TABLE;
```

A **comma** before from

Comment: Yes, i think so anyway, i've added the code i have in my DBHelper class above

Comment: I need a comma before FROM?

Comment: check for all commas before "FROM"

Comment: I dont think a sql syntax has a comma before FROM

Comment: My first problem was solved btw, i had one to many commas, i have changed my code, and it worked. however my view button crashes the app now which is annoying but i'll leave that for tomorrow, thanks for your Help.

Comment: Yes, i have checked the commas but i have a new problem, which was explained , i can explain again if you have time

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't read all your code. But I just quick found your Sql syntax :

```
SELECT  id,forename, surname, housenumber, street, town, county, postcode, phone,  FROM contacts
```

Shouldn't have `,` before `FROM`

Correct one:

```
SELECT  id,forename, surname, housenumber, street, town, county, postcode, phone  FROM contacts
```

Comment: Okay soooo, my view button works now. but my add button still crashes the App. my logcat is above

Comment: Okay so my add works now, but more issues have come up... when i add a new record i can save, or close or update if its an existing record. however they still crash the app. i've posted the new logcat

Comment: :( currently my logcat, I can't know what current error?

Comment: I've updated it

Answer (score 0):

Remove "," after KEY_PHONE in select query

```
 String selectQuery =  "SELECT  " +
            Contact.KEY_ID + ", " +
            Contact.KEY_FORENAME + ", " +
            Contact.KEY_SURNAME + ", " +
            Contact.KEY_HOUSENUMEBR  + ", " +
            Contact.KEY_STREET + ", " +
            Contact.KEY_TOWN + ", " +
            Contact.KEY_COUNTY  + ", " +
            Contact.KEY_POSTCODE + ", " +
            Contact.KEY_PHONE + 
            " FROM " + Contact.TABLE
            + " WHERE " +
            Contact.KEY_ID + "=?";// It's a good practice to use parameter ?, instead of concatenate string
```

Answer (score 0):

If thats creating a problem try using

```
Cursor rows= db.query(TableFile.Table_Name, columns, null, null,null,null,null);
```

Check out for parameters.
1. Table Name
2. array of columns you want
3. "columnName1= ?"
4. array argument for value for columnName1

rest keep null

Hope this helps.

Comment: My problem was solved by removing 1 too many commas, however i have ran into more issues, i've updated my question